# Join a JSON array's property back into one value

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

I have a table with an `nvarchar` column that contains a serialized JSON array.

What I'm trying to do is parse that array and join the value of a property back into one string.

Here's the column content:

[image]

And in my final query, I'd like it come be displayed as one value like "Videowall" in "MergedValues". Obviously, if the array has many items, I'd like to see "Videowall, Factory, Car", etc.

Here's what I tried so far

```
SELECT *,
      (SELECT Name
         FROM OPENJSON(JsonColumn)
         WITH 
         (
          Id   VARCHAR(200) '$.Id',
          Name VARCHAR(200) '$.Name'
         )) 
  FROM MyTable
 WHERE JsonColumn <> '[]'
```

This obvious error comes up

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
> subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
> an expression.

I think it's the joining of the many parsed results that's missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to aggregate the results from the `OPENJSON()` call for each row:

Table:

```
SELECT *
INTO Data
FROM (VALUES
   (0, 0, 25200, '[{"Id":"10564", "Name": "Videowall"}]'),
   (0, 0, 9200, '[{"Id":"10564", "Name": "Videowall"},{"Id":"10565", "Name": "Factory"}]')
) v (OriginalEstimateSeconds, RemainingEstimateSeconds, TimeSpentSeconds, ComponentsJSON)
```

Statement:

```
SELECT
   OriginalEstimateSeconds, RemainingEstimateSeconds, TimeSpentSeconds, ComponentsJSON,
   MergedValues = (
      SELECT STRING_AGG([Name], ',')
      FROM OPENJSON(ComponentsJSON) WITH (Name varchar(100) '$.Name')
   )
FROM Data
```

Result:

```
... ComponentsJSON                                                          MergedValues
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
... [{"Id":"10564", "Name": "Videowall"}]                                   Videowall
... [{"Id":"10564", "Name": "Videowall"},{"Id":"10565", "Name": "Factory"}] Videowall,Factory
```

If the order of the `$.Name` values in the newly generated text is important, you may use the script below:

```
SELECT
   OriginalEstimateSeconds, RemainingEstimateSeconds, TimeSpentSeconds, ComponentsJSON,
   MergedValues = (
      SELECT STRING_AGG(JSON_VALUE([value], '$.Name'), ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY CONVERT(int, [key]))
      FROM OPENJSON(ComponentsJSON)
   )
FROM Data
```

Answer (score 1):

A Subquery is not needed, but `CROSS APPLY` should be used to join the table and `OPENJSON` expression, and use `STRING_AGG()` at the end in order to aggregate the extracted names such as

```
SELECT JsonColumn, STRING_AGG(Name, ',') AS [Merged Values]
  FROM MyTable
 CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(JsonColumn)
  WITH 
  (
   Id   VARCHAR(200) '$.Id',
   Name VARCHAR(200) '$.Name'
  )
 GROUP BY JsonColumn
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=02c6d840f3c6726dee53bf26fccddcf6)</kbd>

Comment: I edited my question. If I try to use this, every row ends up having a column that has all of the possible values that table column has in its serialized JSON.

Comment: As far as I understand(*due to the previous edit*), you also need GROUP BY expression having multiple column within the table @FrancisDucharme